# Edit duplicate comment message in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

When user posts multiple same comments to wordpress error message is displayed saying

```
Duplicate comment detected; it looks as though you’ve already said that!
```

Is there a hook or filter to edit this message? I couldn't find it so far. Or is there some other way of editing it without digging into core?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old but it was one of the few that had the same question I was looking for so once I found the answer I decided to post for reference.

After 4.4 WP finally added a filter to hook this message with which runs by killing the die function and adding a returning an empty value to hook into.

`* @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param int   $dupe_id     ID of the comment identified as a duplicate.
     * @param array $commentdata Data for the comment being created.
     */
    $dupe_id = apply_filters( 'duplicate_comment_id', $dupe_id, $commentdata );`

Starts at ln. 656 in core.
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/comment.php

There is also away to use `add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'enable_duplicate_comments_preprocess_comment');` to enable duplicates. Read more here: https://www.strangerstudios.com/blog/2010/10/duplicate-comment-detected-it-looks-as-though-youve-already-said-that/